# C# MemoryCache, Cannot find out what is happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I created a service supporting my asp.net mvc controller.  The service returns a List. It is a list of custom defined fields that I render in the the create and edit views. Since these fields are defined once I want to return a cache when available and when not, create the cache. Since I am testing I have not defined cache expiration.

When I execute the Edit action this service helps mapping the queried values to the cached list of customfields. What happens is that my object in cache is modified.

I am familiair that the MemoryCache contains a reference and that is does not contain a copy of the object. What I do not understand is why the MemoryCache is modified, when I am actually working with an object that - in my view - is not a reference to the cache and had been passed to the method and has no ref or out parameters defined. For me the reference is in a totally different scope?

I tried all sorts of things but I am missing the essential issue that is causing this behavior and I really want to figure out what is happening here. Is there a broader scope of the reference. Do local variables are still being shared among methods?

This is the method in the service that either returns the cached information, or queries the database and stores the result in the cache. It is used by the  Create and Edit actions. Notice that the value property is defined as being null so that a Create actions starts with empty fields.

```
public IList<CustomField> GetCustomFields()
        {
            var result = MemoryCache.Default["cache_customfield"] as List<CustomField>;
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = session.Query<CustomField>()
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(c => new CustomField
                        {
                            Id = c.Id,
                            Name = c.Name,
                            Value = null
                        })
                        .ToList();

                MemoryCache.Default["cache_customfield"] = result;
            }
            return result;
        }

public static IList<CustomField> MapValues(IList<CustomField> fields, IDictionary<string,string> values = null)
        {
            // the cached information still has value properties that are null
            var a = MemoryCache.Default["cache_customfield"] as List<CustomField>;

            foreach (var field in fields.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            {
                var persistedValue = string.Empty;
                values?.TryGetValue(field.Id, out persistedValue);
                field.Value = persistedValue;
            }

            // the cached information suddenly has value properties that are defined, however the 'fields' parameter has no reference to the original information?!
            var b = MemoryCache.Default["cache_customfield"] as List<CustomField>;

            return fields;
        }
```

I doubt these have much impact on the situation, but these are the actions on the controllers for Create and Edit.

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var ticketService = BusinessServiceFacade.GetTicketService(RavenSession);

            var vm = new TicketViewModel();
            vm.Controls = ControlViewModel.CreateControls(ticketService.GetCustomFields());
            return View(vm);
        }

public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            var ticketService = BusinessServiceFacade.GetTicketService(RavenSession);
            var ticket = RavenSession.Load<Ticket>(id);
            var customfieldValues = ticket.Attributes.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);

            var vm = new TicketViewModel(ticket);

            var listOfCustomFields = TicketService.MapValues(ticketService.GetCustomFields(), customfieldValues);
            vm.Controls = ControlViewModel.CreateControls(listOfCustomFields);

            return View(vm);
        }
```

So essentially, why is my cache modified in the MapValues method when the fields parameter has a scope on his own (not ref or out). Really want to understand what is going on here.

**UPDATE:**

After making the modification by supplying a new List reference I am not noticing any change.

It looks like the reference is still passed forward from the local variable to the newly created as parameter. One thing would be to entirely build up a new list with freshly created CustomField objects but when possible I would like to avoid that.

I am possibly making a simple mistake.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var ticketService = BusinessServiceFacade.GetTicketService(RavenSession);

        var vm = new TicketViewModel();

        var fields = ticketService.GetCustomFields();
        vm.Controls = ControlViewModel.CreateControls(new List<CustomField>(fields));

        return View(vm);
    }

   public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        var ticketService = BusinessServiceFacade.GetTicketService(RavenSession);
        var ticket = RavenSession.Load<Ticket>(id);
        var customfieldValues = ticket.Attributes.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);

        var vm = new TicketViewModel(ticket);

        var fields = ticketService.GetCustomFields();
        var listOfCustomFields = TicketService.MapValues(new List<CustomField>(fields), customfieldValues);
        vm.Controls = ControlViewModel.CreateControls(listOfCustomFields);

        return View(vm);
    }
```

**Solution**

Do a deep copy.

```
public static IList<CustomField> MapValues(IList<CustomField> fields, IDictionary<string,string> values = null)
        {
            // break reference, deep copy to new list
            var oldList = (List<CustomField>) fields;
            var newList = oldList.ConvertAll(c => new CustomField(c.Id, c.Name, c.Visible, c.Type, c.TypeFormat, c.Value));

            foreach (var field in newList.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            {
                var persistedValue = string.Empty;
                values?.TryGetValue(field.Id, out persistedValue);
                field.Value = persistedValue;
            }

            return newList;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TicketService.MapValues(ticketService.GetCustomFields()...
```

Within your `Edit` method, you call `MapValues` passing in the result of `GetCustomFields`, and that result is the cached list. So, within `MapValues`, all of `a`, `b`, and `fields` are references to the *same* list (the cached object). That's why you see the changes you make to `fields` also appear in `b`.

> why is my cache modified in the MapValues method when the fields parameter has a scope on his own (not ref or out).

Yes, `fields` is scoped to the method. But I think you're confusing the difference between 1) changing the value of `fields` -- which is a reference to a list. And 2)  changing the actual *list* that `fields` references.  Yes, the changes you make to `fields` is scoped to this method (e.g. it won't affect the value that was passed in). However, as long as it points to a specific list, any changes you make to that list can be observed by other references to the same list.  So, the scope of `fields` *doesn't* mean the changes you make to the *list* will be scoped to this method.

---

In response to the comment below, if you do something like this:

```
IList<CustomField> originalList = ticketService.GetCustomFields();
IList<CustomField> newList = new List<CustomField>(originalList);
```

and pass in the new list to `MapValues` (`TicketService.MapValues(newList...`) then the changes within `MapValues` won't affect the list referenced by the `originalList`.  Because now you have two different lists.

---

**Update:** As commented below, I didn't notice you were modifying individual items within the list. So you need to *deep-copy* in that case.  In this specific case, deep-copy isn't too bad since you only have a couple properties to copy:

```
IList<CustomField> originalList = ticketService.GetCustomFields();
IList<CustomField> newList = originalList
    .Select(x => new CustomField
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Value = x.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

However, you can see how this could get problematic quickly as you have more properties or properties of complex types (need to copy properties of properties, etc.).  There are solutions such as serializing/deserializing the object to copy but I'd consider a different design first. Like I said, in your case, I think manually copying a couple properties isn't too bad.

Comment: So, if I understand this correct. The modifications on the supplied `fields` parameter still have an effect on the original object that has been created in the GetCustomFields() method an passed along as the `fields` parameter? 



Is there any way I can break this behavior? I assume making a copy of the object that is returned from GetCustomFields() will also have a reference to the original thus modifying the cached information?

Comment: If by "copy" you mean assigning it to another variable, then yes, it will have no affect -- you'll observe the same behavior.  See the update.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This really helps clearing up the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately the references is still being forwarded when I create a new list and pass the values.

I assume by creating a local variable and refering to the list, that reference is still being kept in the newly created list object.

Ill add the changed code to my original question.

Comment: @MichaSchopman I wasn't paying attention to the fact that you're not modifying the list but you're modifying the individual items within the list.  In that case, you not only have to create a new list but also have to make copies of the individual items (this is called a "deep copy").

Comment: Ok, I could this working now. Very glad. I modified the MapValues to create a deep copy of the List. Just needed a few lines of code and a new constructor on the model so I could inject all the values.

I updated the initial question with the solution